# What geographical area would be the easiest start for players in a Vampire : The Masquerade today?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

After discussing to some friends that visits some country all over the world, I find myself thinking about "Where it will be easy to be a vampire?" (Yes I know, I ask myself weirds questions), that I transform into "What geographical area would be the easiest start for players in a Vampire : The Masquerade today?"

As I search, I decide to cut the world in 9 areas (I tried to use facts and only that, and it was really interesting):

- Western Europe: No bearing weapons allowed, so hunting is easier in early night, but a lot of peoples doesn't go outside in late night.
- Eastern Europe: More weapons, weapon bearing allowed officially or in a roundabout way so hunting is harder, but government have more information control so the Masquerade is easier to preserve, but Firstlight will find you easier too.
- North America: Weapon bearing allowed in most cases so hunting more dangerous, but their is peoples are outside all night long so it's easier to find a prey, but everything is open 24/7 so you can live without needing a ghoul.
- South America: Like the Eastern Europe, but with more nature, so Werewolves might go kill you more often
- Africa: The whole area is more or less in war, live as human is hard, and so it is to Kindred
- Middle East: The Antediluvians are here and awakens, so it's not a good area to be a Kindred (or a human bein)
- North Asia: Most part of North Asia is the Russia, so it's like the Eastern Europe
- South Asia: Governement is strong, so the masquerade is easier to preserve, but Firstlight will find you easier too. Kuei-Jins are here so maybe it's hard to be a Kindred
- Oceania: "The whole fauna and flora want to kill you" meme don't apply to you, and weapon controll is getting bigger now, so hunting is easier

So I think Oceania is the easiest area to start as a vampire, followed by Western Europe and North America. But I might be wrong in the statements I made with my researches (as I just take 2 hours to do so).

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a question to me, but rather a discussion prompt. These don't really work on a Q&A site, but a much better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137).

Comment: I agree with @Someone_Evil but, notwithstanding, you have a pretty poor understanding of the world.

Comment: This question is on hold right now, but in general I'll mention that Kindred have supernatural abilities which make "mundane" features of government and daily living a lot less important to them than to mortals. The things that make Kindred existence difficult are generally the Masquerade (and technology making it harder to maintain) and other supernatural beings which can counter your powers while challenging you with their own. The features you describe seem mostly unimportant to vampires, in addition to not being accurate (based on my own travels).

Answer (score 4):

**Wherever you happen to live.**

The place you live is likely the place you have the most experience with, so it would be the place that would be easiest for you to present authentically when you're GMing it.